# Magento CE 1.5.0.1 support PHP5.5?

Tags: php-5.4, magento-1.5, ce-1.5.0.1, php-5.5

My store currently uses Magento CE 1.5.0.1 and it works well on server with PHP 5.4.45. Now the server will be upgraded to PHP 5.5. Will my store (Magento CE 1.5.0.1) supports PHP 5.5?

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from this article which states that magento 1.9 has added support for php 5.5. I would say no , but it is quiet difficult to say.

https://www.whitefirdesign.com/blog/2013/12/10/using-magento-with-php-5-4-and-5-5/